# How to execute incremental ReadFeed in CosmosDb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm writing a tool that runs periodically and reads and processes batches of documents from a CosmosDb collection. I'd like to read all documents that have not been processed yet including changed and added documents.

[List (ReadFeed) Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-documents) states that:

> ReadFeed can be used to retrieve (...) the incremental changes to documents within the collection.

and that this can be done by setting the `If-None-Match` request header `etag` received in the response header:

> The logical sequence number (LSN) of last document returned in the response.
> incremental `ReadDocumentFeed` can be resumed by resubmitting this value in `If-None-Match`.

but there is no such header in the response.

I used both REST API and .NET Cosmos SDK v3 and tried setting `If-None-Match` header to:

1. `_etag` of the last processed document
2. `etag` of the container

But I'm getting the same, full set of documents each time.

A sample request I have:

```
GET /dbs/myData/colls/myItems/docs HTTP/2
Host: cosmos-local.documents.azure.com
authorization: type%3dmaster%26ver%3d1.0%26sig%3d...%2f...%2f...%3d
x-ms-date: Fri, 19 Feb 2021 08:44:23 GMT
x-ms-version: 2018-12-31
if-none-match: "44000253-0000-0d00-0000-601428c90000"
accept: */*
```

I tried these `etag` formats in `If-None-Match`:

```
"\"44000253-0000-0d00-0000-601428c90000\""
"44000253-0000-0d00-0000-601428c90000"
44000253-0000-0d00-0000-601428c90000
```

a response:

```
HTTP/2 200 
cache-control: no-store, no-cache
pragma: no-cache
content-type: application/json
content-location: https://cosmos-local.documents.azure.com/dbs/myData/colls/myItems/docs
server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
x-ms-activity-id: 765ea7f5-40c6-48fb-bf90-7b3b506b0b82
x-ms-last-state-change-utc: Thu, 11 Feb 2021 08:35:47.977 GMT
x-ms-resource-quota: documentSize=51200;documentsSize=52428800;documentsCount=-1;collectionSize=52428800;
x-ms-resource-usage: documentSize=0;documentsSize=238;documentsCount=19;collectionSize=243;
x-ms-schemaversion: 1.11
lsn: 174
x-ms-item-count: 19
x-ms-request-charge: 2.53
x-ms-alt-content-path: dbs/myData/colls/myItems
x-ms-content-path: eiBDAJIWdUc=
x-ms-documentdb-partitionkeyrangeid: 0
x-ms-xp-role: 1
x-ms-global-committed-lsn: 173
x-ms-number-of-read-regions: 0
x-ms-transport-request-id: 1
x-ms-cosmos-llsn: 174
x-ms-session-token: 0:-1#174
x-ms-request-duration-ms: 1.002
x-ms-serviceversion: version=2.11.0.0
x-ms-gatewayversion: version=2.11.0
date: Fri, 19 Feb 2021 10:45:10 GMT
```

Other attempts I made:

1. Set `A-IM` header to `Incremental feed` - got an error in the response
2. Set value from `lsn` header in the `If-None-Match` - got full set
3. Use `ChangeFeedProcessor`. It looks like what I need, but it keeps waiting for new data and I'd like it to shut down / timeout if there are no new changes.
4. Check if setting `x-ms-max-item-count` makes any difference - it doesn't seem to

So the questions are:

1. How to run incremental ReadFeed in CosmosDb?
2. Is there a better approach to read all documents in a collection incrementally, in separate runs?

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to use Change Feed. You can shut this down if you want. Just call StopAsync() on the processor object. If you're running this on a schedule you can host in Azure Functions and run it from a timer. When it starts up it will connect to the lease collection and start processing again from the last lsn. When it's done processing, call StopAsync() and it will shut down.